# Why is the nested for loop not completing?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I have a nested for loop which is not not completing/exiting
It is getting stuck in the second loop:

```
for (var j = 0; next.className != "rfccs" && next !== null; j++)
```

It only gets stuck when 'next' IS null.

My Code:

```
var filtertypes = document.getElementsByClassName("rfccs"); // filtertypes is an array of all filter type headers
var next = null; // placeholder for the next sibling element
var tout = document.getElementById("testout"); //test
tout.innerHTML = "init "; //test

for (var i = 0; i < filtertypes.length; i++) {
    filtertypes[i].className += " fhead" + i; // adds a unique class to every filter type header div
    var filtertype = filtertypes[i]; // sets filtertype to the current filter type header
    next = filtertype.nextElementSibling; // gets the next sibling

    for (var j = 0; next.className != "rfccs" && next !== null; j++) { // adds the same class name to all filters in the same filter type
        next.className += " ftype" + i;
        next.innerHTML += i;
        next = next.nextElementSibling;
        tout.innerHTML += "i = " + i + "; j = " + j + "///";
        if (next == null) {
            tout.innerHTML += "DONE";
        }
    }
    tout.innerHTML += "~~~~";
}
```

I know my tracing/debugging code is really messy.

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wJBJL/5/)

Comment: If ``next`` is ``null``, your code will fail because the first thing that happens is that it will check the property ``next.className``. You need to swap the checks.

Comment: @DerekThomasTran: In addition to what `mzdeler` said. Here is the link to the MDN documentation for [**logical operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) it explains really well the order in which those operators do their checks. I hope you will find this helpful to prevent similar future issues :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var next = null;
next.className; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
```

Do your check for `null` before checking `.className`

```
next !== null && next.className !== "rfccs" // false if null
```

Further, as any *HTMLElement* will be *truthy* by logical operators, you can skip the `!== null` for it entirely

```
next && next.className !== "rfccs" // falsy if `next` falsy
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
for (var j = 0; next != null && next.className != "rfccs"; j++)
```

if `next is null` `next.className` will fail and hence javascript loop

see if this is what you expect 
http://jsfiddle.net/wJBJL/6/